# Get timestamp from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I can't figure out how to extract the timestamp from a pandas column.

With the following code I am getting the following information.

```
print("Nested ----------------------------")
print(type(nested_full['data.tick_timestamp']))

ts2 = nested_full['data.tick_timestamp']
print("type of timestamp")
print(ts2)
diff_seconds = util.seconds_since_mightnight(ts2) # Fail here because of invalid data??


Nested ----------------------------
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
type of timestamp
0    1574417975007
Name: data.tick_timestamp, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need scalar from one element `Series`, so use [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html) and select first value:

```
out = nested_full['data.tick_timestamp'].iat[0]
```

Or [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
out = nested_full['data.tick_timestamp'].iloc[0]
```

---

If want numpy repr of datetimes:

```
out = nested_full['data.tick_timestamp'].values[0]
#pandas 0.24+
out = nested_full['data.tick_timestamp'].to_numpy()[0]
```